# Difference of @value and FLOOR(@value) is 0 for DECIMAL type

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, floor

A lot of answers here say use

```
SELECT @value - FLOOR(@value)
```

to get the decimal part of a number. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882752/817630) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418635/817630) for examples.

I'm getting what I consider to be weird behavior when I do this.

```
DECLARE @test DECIMAL(38, 8)
SET @test = 123.05468800

SELECT @test - FLOOR(@test)

Result: 0
```

I can do

```
SELECT 123.05468800 - FLOOR(123.05468800)

Result: 0.05468800
```

and I can change the type of `@test` to `FLOAT` and it works. Also `FLOOR(@test)` returns `123` as expected.

I imagine this has something to with precision of the decimal type, but [the only MSDN page I could find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) on the subject is really sparse.

So what's going on? Why don't I get the decimal portion `.05468800`? And what should I be doing or using to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test DECIMAL(38, 8), @test2 DECIMAL(28, 8)
SET @test = 123.05468800
SET @test2 = 123.05468800

SELECT 
    @test as test, 
    FLOOR(@test) AS floortest, 
    @test-FLOOR(@test) AS broken, 
    @test - CAST(FLOOR(@test) AS DECIMAL(38, 8)) AS fixed
INTO gbntest;

SELECT 
    @test2 as test, 
    FLOOR(@test2) AS floortest, 
    @test-FLOOR(@test2) AS working
INTO gbntest2;

SELECT 
    123.05468800 as test,
    FLOOR(123.05468800) as floortest,
    123.05468800 - FLOOR(123.05468800) as working
INTO gbntest3;

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'gbntest%';
DROP TABLE gbntest;
DROP TABLE gbntest2;
DROP TABLE gbntest3;
```

Note the middle 2 for gbntest are `decimal (38,0)`

However, with constants or `decimal (28,8)` it works. So does `(29,8)` and `(30,8)`

But then with `(31,8)` you get `(38,7)` back.

The MSDN ["Precision, Scale, and Length"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) describes why

```
                precision                                 scale
 ...
 e1 - e2        max(s1, s2) + max(p1-s1, p2-s2) + 1       max(s1, s2)
```

For (31,8), you get a precision of (40, 8)

```
max(8,0) + max(31-8, 31-0) + 1 -> 8 + 31 + 1 -> 40
max(8,0) -> 8
```

`(40,8)` *should* be adjusted down to `(38,6)`. So I've bollixed my calculation somewhere :-) but I hope you get the idea...

Comment: Very nice!  I didn't dig deep enough into precision behavior, apparently!

Comment: Ah, I understand. The key is the footnote at the bottom of the page you linked. "...precision [has] an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, the...scale is reduced." So now my question is, why doesn't FLOOR return DECIMAL(38,8) in this context? [The MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178531.aspx) says it should have the same result type as the input.