# Date difference (in years) incl. year fraction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a simple way to calculate the difference between two dates that:

1. expresses it as the number of years incl. the year fraction; and
2. takes account of leap years?

For example, the difference between 1st March 2011 and 1st March 2012 is 1 year.  However, if I use DATEDIFF(day,..,..) and divide by 365 I get an (undesirable) answer of 1.00274 because of the leap year.

To be clear, I need any year fraction as well (ie. not just the whole number of years).  For example the difference between 1st March 2011 and 3rd March 2012 is 1.005479 (1 year + 2/365 years).  The difference between 1st March 2011 and 29th February 2012 is 0.997268 (0 year + 365/366 years)

So, in summary, the output (in DECIMAL(7,6)) from the above two examples would be:

1.000000
1.005479
0.997268

Comment: Could you please tell me what exactly you want as output in your above example?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882667/how-can-i-get-the-fraction-of-the-decimal-in-sql

Comment: But how should a "year fraction" be defined (it's not a well known term, so far as I'm aware)? Based on the specific dates, you might need to account for a year being 366 days long instead of 365. E.g. what is the expected output for the difference between 1st March 2011 and 29th February 2012?

Comment: Can you also give the expected output for the difference between 29/02/2012 and 28/02/2013, and again for 29/02/2012 and 01/03/2013 please?

Comment: I edited my post at the same time that you posted.  I would like the denominator in the year fraction to be the number of days in the forthcoming year.  Which, now that I think about it, sort of answers my question (save for there being an in-built T-SQL function that does this).

Comment: Thanks Damien.  Your comment and valexhome's post have made me question my logic.  I'm going to rethink it.  Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Here is a query. But there is a logical error in your example. I think "difference between 1st March 2011 and 3rd March 2012 is 1.005479 (1 year + 2/365 years)" should be (1 year + 2/366 years) because 29.02.2012 in between 3rd March 2011 and 3rd March 2012 so in the last year 366 days.

```
    Declare @BDate datetime
    Declare @EDate datetime
    SET @BDate='2011-03-01'
    SET @EDate='2012-02-29'

    select 

    datediff(year,@BDate,@Edate)- 
    case when dateadd(year,datediff(year,@BDate,@Edate),@BDate)>@Edate then 1 else 0 end 
    +cast(datediff(day,dateadd(year,datediff(year,@BDate,@Edate)-
    case when dateadd(year,datediff(year,@BDate,@Edate),@BDate)>@Edate then 1 else 0 end   ,@BDate),@Edate) as float)/
cast(datediff(day,dateadd(year,-1,@Edate),@Edate) as float)
```

Comment: This works most of the time, but it fails on '2011-12-31' and '2012-01-01'. I noticed this after upvoting

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I do need to rethink my logic.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I've fixed this issue try new version.

Answer (score 3):

I think this works (I've hopefully picked names you can follow):

```
declare @StartTime datetime
declare @EndTime datetime

select @StartTime = '20110301',@EndTime = '20120303'

select YearsDiffNorm + ((DaysIntoYear * 1.0) / (DaysIntoYear + DaysRemainingInYear))
from (
select
    YearsDiffNorm,
    DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(YEAR,YearsDiffNorm,@StartTime),@EndTime) as DaysIntoYear,
    DATEDIFF(day,@EndTime,DATEADD(YEAR,YearsDiffNorm+1,@StartTime)) as DaysRemainingInYear
from (
select CASE WHEN DATEADD(year,YearsDiff,@StartTime) > @EndTime then YearsDiff - 1 else YearsDiff END as YearsDiffNorm
from (
    select DATEDIFF(year,@StartTime,@EndTime) as YearsDiff
) t
) t2
) t3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT Cast(DateDiff(yyyy, '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01') As VARCHAR) + 'Yer : '
+ Cast(DateDiff(mm, '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01') As VARCHAR) + 'Mon : '
+ Cast(DateDiff(dd, '2011-03-01', '2012-03-01') As VARCHAR) + 'Dte'
```

Hope this helps you, thank you.

Comment: Thanks but it's not quite what I'm after.  I should have been more explicit in my post, which I will edit.  I want any year fraction as well as the whole number of years.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   DECLARE @stdate datetime,@eddate datetime
    SET @stdate='2007-02-01'
    SET @eddate='2012-03-03'

    ;WITH CTE as (
    select DATEDIFF(yy,@stdate,convert(datetime,cast(DATEPART(year,@eddate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(month,@stdate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(dd,@stdate) as varchar))) yrs,
    DATEDIFF(dd,convert(datetime,cast(DATEPART(year,@eddate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(month,@stdate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(dd,@stdate) as varchar)),@eddate) as dayss,
    CAST(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(mm,datediff(mm,-1,(convert(datetime,cast(DATEPART(year,@eddate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(month,@stdate) as varchar)+'-'+cast(DATEPART(dd,@stdate) as varchar)))),-1)) = 29 then 366 else 365 end as float) as ydays
    )
    select yrs+dayss/cast(ydays as float) from CTE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = '2019-02-28', @ToDate DATETIME = '2020-02-26',
@diff_year_temp int, @diff_year int,@diff_year_frac float,@ToDateDays float,@FromDateDays float,@y_to int,@y_from int,@diff float,
@FromDec float,@JanTo float,@JanToFrac float,@FromDecFrac float,@ToDateplusone datetime,@FromplusToyear datetime

set @diff_year_temp=datediff(year,@FromDate,@ToDate)
set @FromplusToyear=case when DATEPART(day,@FromDate)=29 and datepart(month,@FromDate)=2 then dateadd(day,1,dateadd(year,@diff_year_temp,@FromDate)) else  dateadd(year,@diff_year_temp,@FromDate) end
set @ToDateplusone=dateadd(day,1,@ToDate)
set @y_to = datepart(year,@ToDate)
set @y_from=datepart(year,@FromDate)
set @FromDec=datediff(day,@FromDate,cast(CONCAT(@y_from,'-12-31') as date))+1
set @JanTo=datediff(day,cast(CONCAT(@y_to,'-01-01') as date),@ToDate)+1
set @ToDateDays = DATEDIFF(day,  cast(@y_to as char(4)),  cast(@y_to+1 as char(4))) 
set @FromDateDays = DATEDIFF(day,  cast(@y_from as char(4)),  cast(@y_from+1 as char(4)))

set @FromDecFrac=@FromDec/@FromDateDays
set @JanToFrac=@JanTo/@ToDateDays
set @diff_year=case when @ToDateplusone >= @FromplusToyear  then @diff_year_temp else @diff_year_temp-1 end
set @diff_year_frac=case when @ToDateplusone >= @FromplusToyear then datediff(day,@FromplusToyear,@ToDateplusone)/@ToDateDays  else  @JanToFrac+@FromDecFrac end
set @diff=@diff_year+@diff_year_frac

select @diff
```