# Ceilling or floor on condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a query like this:

```
select cast(a as Float)/cast(b as Float) as c from x
```

here i want to apply a condition.if `c` has value after point is >=5 for example 1.55
then i will apply ceilling otherwise for example 1.45 i will apply floor
I tried `round(a/b,0)` but it is not returning expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @val1 decimal(15,4)
set @val1=1.4
select CASE WHEN @val1-floor(@val1) >0.4 THEN ceiling(@val1) ELSE floor(@val1) END
```

[REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8882752/1008219)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that at least one of the arguments "a" or "b" is CAST as a FLOAT as per the following:

```
select ROUND(15.5/CAST(10 AS FLOAT), 0) -- returns 2
select ROUND(14.5/CAST(10 AS FLOAT), 0)  -- returns 1
```

That will ensure that you get REAL division (not integer division).